# How to know if all the Thread Pool's thread are already done with its tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I have this application that will recurse all folders in a given directory and look for PDF. If a PDF file is found, the application will count its pages using ITextSharp. I did this by using a thread to recursively scan all the folders for pdf, then if then PDF is found, this will be queued to the thread pool. The code looks like this:

```
//spawn a thread to handle the processing of pdf on each folder.
                var th = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    pdfDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(pdfPath);
                    processDir(pdfDirectories);
                });
                th.Start();



 private void processDir(string[] dirs)
        {
            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf");
                processFiles(pdfFiles);

                string[] newdir = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
                processDir(newdir);
            }
        }



private void processFiles(string[] files)
        {
            foreach (var pdf in files)
            {
                ThreadPoolHelper.QueueUserWorkItem(
                    new { path = pdf },
                    (data) => { processPDF(data.path); }
                    );
            }
        }
```

My problem is, how do i know that the thread pool's thread has finished processing all the queued items so i can tell the user that the application is done with its intended task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally I would do something like this by having a counter variable.
For each work item you queue in the `ThreadPool` add one to the counter variable.
Then when it is processed you would decrease the counter variable.

Be sure that you do the incrementing and decrementing via the methods on the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class as this will ensure that things are done in a thread-safe manner.

Once the counter hits zero you could flag that the tasks are completed using a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

If you have access to .NET 4 then you can use the new [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28VS.100%29.aspx) class to do a similar thing.

Comment: I have done a similar logic to this. Only i used the ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads. I set the MaxThreads the pools should be using by 20. So at the last of the task i checked if the available threads are equal to the max that i set. Unfortunately this fails. I will research on that Manual Reset Event.

Comment: @mcxiand: You can't use the ThreadPool counters because other code (lib) could create threads and the TP is recycling/deleting them.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Is that so? From what i understood is that, the ThreadPool will be queued of task by QueueUserWorkItem method. Can you give more details about your comment? it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @mcxiand: You have no way of guaranteeing that all the threads in the ThreadPool will be free once you have finished processing your items.
It may well be the case that all threads become available once your items are processed, but there is one ThreadPool per process, so any other code that is loaded may well be using the ThreadPool to do things at the same time and your code should never rely on assumptions about the numbers of threads.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. I already understood it. I also changed my code as what JonC said above.

Answer (score 2):

1) How to know if all threads are finished?

You will have to let the Threads do their own check-in/check-out, by bracketing your code between:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref jobCounter);
// your code
Interlocked.Decrement(ref jobCounter);
```

If this messes up your anonymous delegates too much then just use wrapper methods. You are probably going to have to add exception handling too.

The interlocked approach still eaves the problem of waiting for it to become 0, a loop with Sleep() is a weak but in this case viable solution.

2) You are starting threads in a recursive Tree walker. Be careful, you are probably creating too much of them and that will hurt performance.

Comment: i only have one thread to do the recursing and queue every pdf files found in each folder by the thread

Comment: OK, it is more linear. And from the comments you throttle MaxThreads. Still requires tuning and changing MaxThreads is a sledgehammer.

Comment: I controlled the MaxThreads because on this thread, i am updating UI control using BeginInvoke. UI will freeze if there are lots of threads running. Any recommendations?